Overriding the default ping protocol for native Javascript websockets
I am attempting to create a protocol for handling stale websocket connections for my Expo (React Native) project on both the client and server side. Since the 'ws' package has built-in callback handling for the 'pong' event (and for sending a ping), management on the server (NodeJS) is easy enough.
Where I am having trouble is with the client, as the native WebSocket object does not present a callback for its response to pings from the server. It does respond to pings from the server with the correct opcode (0x9), but such messages are never passed to the WebSocket.onmessage handler.
This is my attempt at a client-side ping handler:
const heartbeat = () => {
            console.log("heartbeat");

            clearTimeout(pingTimeout!);

            pingTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
                socket.close();
                setResetConnection(rc => !rc);
            }, HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL + HEARTBEAT_LATENCY);
};

socket.onmessage = (event) => {
            console.log("message");

            if (event.data instanceof Blob) {
                console.log("received ping");
                heartbeat();
                const response = new ArrayBuffer(1);
                const view = new Uint8Array(response);
                view[0] = 0x9;
                socket.send(view);
                return;
            }

            [...remaining onmessage code...]
}

With socket initialized as var socket = new WebSocket("ws://ipaddr:8080");
As mentioned, the pong is sent to the server accordingly without allowing the client any space for additional logic. I would like to find a way to override this behavior without constructing my own ping/pong protocol.

why do you need to do this? It should be handled automatically at a level lower than application. You can always just send a small "normal" message that you watch for on the client if the socket lifetime events aren't enough for your application.

I want the client to be able to understand whether or not the connection is stale; at the moment it will continue to send packets to the server because it does not know when the connection is terminated. I could just send a regular custom message but this would eliminate the need for the preexisting ping/pong protocol which I figure is better to build off of than creating my own system

socket.onclose() will fire if the connection is terminated.

I had thought that event wouldn't suit my case but it works great. Thank you!

@dandavis is correct; using socket.onclose() is perfectly acceptable
